# How to bind DataGrid.SelectedItem in DataTemplate

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Hope it's not a dup.  I'm using Silverlight 4.

I have a collection *MyProjects* from my ViewModel *MyVM* binding to a datagrid *MainDataGrid*.

I also have a RowDetailsTemplate to show several buttons.

I have Command binding on these buttons.  The command binding *Command="{Binding Path=EditCommand}"* appears working but I just can't get the CommandParameter binding working.  Is Element name working inside a DataTemplate?  What's the best way to pass in SelectedItem/SelectedDataRow via a CommandParameter binding inside a DataTemplate?

Thanks for your help.

```
        <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="MainDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataContext="{StaticResource MyVM}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyProjects}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">

            <sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="Ivory" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource DataGridRowDetailsButtonStyle}"
                                Command="{Binding Path=EditCommand}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem}">Edit</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a property 'MySelectedItem' in the view model (where you define your EditCommand) and make it bound to your datagrid's selectedItem.

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}">
```

then you can probably do

```
CommandParameter="{Binding MySelectedItem}"
```